# Why doesn't SIFT work for 8 bit images (JPEG) in OpenCV with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg, 8-bit

I used SIFT for all my other 24 bit JPEG images without any problems, however, the 8-bit one always give me the following error.

image is empty or has incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function cv::SIFT::operator ()

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import os 
import glob
import scipy.cluster
os.chdir('\mydirectory')
images = []

for infile in glob.glob('./*.jpg'):
  pic = cv2.imread(infile,0)
  images.append(pic)

my_set = images
descriptors = np.array([])
feaL=np.array([])

for pic in my_set:
  kp, des = cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute(pic, None)
  feaL=np.append(feaL,des.shape[0])
  descriptors = np.append(descriptors, des)
```

Then the error "image is empty or has incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function cv::SIFT::operator ()" pops up.

Comment: sift is generally performed on grayscale images, which are 8 bit. can yo post code?

Comment: I just added code, thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: After typing this I just saw the grayscale flag on `imread`. Try printing the images as they are read in, it sounds like `imread` may be silently failing and leaving you with empty Mats.**

`cv2.SIFT.detectAndCompute` never takes anything other than 8-bit grayscale, so I'm not sure that you actually did use SIFT on a 24-bit image without problems.

[cv2.SIFT.detectAndCompute](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d0/d13/classcv_1_1Feature2D.html#a8be0d1c20b08eb867184b8d74c15a677)

```
Python: cv2.SIFT.detectAndCompute(image, mask[, descriptors[, useProvidedKeypoints]]) → keypoints, descriptors
```

So to change to 8 bit grayscale immediately prior to detection and extraction:

```
for pic in my_set:
    pic = cv2.cvtColor(pic, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kp, des = cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute(pic, None)
```

Of course that is a dumb place to put it, but it's up to you to figure out if you need to keep the BGR originals or not, etc.

Comment: I double checked my code again. cv2.imread(infile,0) reads images in gray scale. It works good for 24 bit images. For 8 bit one, I couldn't even read them in. All I got is "None" or '[]'.

Comment: Ah, it sounded like you claimed to be running SIFT on 24 bit images. You should share samples of the images you are working with.

Comment: Please see below dropbox link for 5 sample images. The images that I have problem with are named as "Bosses_pay_boost_beats_workers" and "High_oil_prices_boost_BPs_profit". Thank you again.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/p19v81xzdmf7gq5/sample%20images.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sorry I took a minute to get back.  
Those files are GIFs! It is failing because OpenCV relies on file extensions to know how to read a file, and they are misnamed as JPEGs.

Comment: me@computermachine:~/sopython$ file High_oil_prices_boost_BPs_profit.jpg 
High_oil_prices_boost_BPs_profit.jpg: GIF image data, version 89a, 203 x 152
me@computermachine:~/sopython$ file Bosses_pay_boost_beats_workers.jpg 
Bosses_pay_boost_beats_workers.jpg: GIF image data, version 89a, 203 x 152
me@computermachine:~/sopython$ file 75-year-old_was_murdered_-_police_1843.jpg 
75-year-old_was_murdered_-_police_1843.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02
me@computermachine:~/sopython$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I saved these GIFs as JPEG file and now everything is working!

Comment: Good answer, your link is broken BTW

Comment: @DarkCygnus just noticed this. better late than never I hope - fixed the link to go to the new docs!

Answer (score 2):

I answered a different user that encountered the same error while using `cv2.SIFT().detectAndCompute()` in-depth in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652549/12246382).

The sift functions (at least specifically `.detectAndCompute()` )
**ONLY accepts images with 8 bit integer values.**

Before using sift on an image, convert it into 8bit using something like
`image8bit = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype('uint8')`