# How to deal with depth of image when using SIFT in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I want to use SIFT in my processing using opencv in python. I have a gray level image of tissue, I have segmented that image into Patches and I want to find key points on each Patch (`here Patch1`) using SIFT.

here is part of my code for this:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp,des = sift.detectAndCompute(Patch1,None)
```

However, when running, it give me the error of image depth:

```
error:(-5) image is empty or has incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function detectAndCompute
```

Then when I try to convert the image again to gray scale it gives this error:

```
error: depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor
```

The same errors happen when I try to use ORB too.

My original images have `.png` format. I did lots of processing on the original image to get i.e. `Patch1`. May it be because I have done some changes during my processing? 
Do you know what I should do? or what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python opencv SIFT doesn't work for 8 bit images (JPEG)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597580/python-opencv-sift-doesnt-work-for-8-bit-images-jpeg)